# Rails views showing formatting input in double curly braces like {{parameter}} instead of actual values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error while using Rails 2.3.8 for following fundtions

distance_of_time_in_words

shows

{{count}} days remaining

and errors for forms

Restful authentication login shows errors like following for invalid form

{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved
There were problems with the following fields:
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}

I suspect that formatting is not getting applied correctly. Has anyone faced similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen that a lot recently. You probably have an incompatible version of the i18n gem installed. Version 0.5 broke some applications. Try downgrading to v. 0.4.2 or below. (0.3.7 did it for me)