# Weird Rails ActiveModel::Errors: ...must be greater than {{count}}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

When I try to save a certain of my ActiveRecord instances, I get this validation error

```
"Weight must be greater than {{count}}"
```

The model file specifies the command

```
validates_numericality_of :weight, :greater_than => 10, :less_than_or_equal_to => 900,  :unless => :is_spia?
```

So why does the error read `{{count}}` instead of just `10`? And what's the proper thing to do about it?

Sys: Rails 2.3.5 Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Deleted my answer... my bad for not reading close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem [Rails views showing formatting input in double curly braces like {{parameter}} instead of actual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471484/rails-views-showing-formatting-input-in-double-curly-braces-like-parameter-i/4473368#4473368) but best if you could upgrade to latest rails or at least rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, "5.1.2 Error Message Interpolation" and "4.3 Pluralization". It might be easiest to override the message for the validation, either inline or in your en.yml (or equivalent) to use {{weight}} rather than {{count}}.

Comment: This looks pretty slick, but I don't quite see how to proceed. Am I to interpolate `count` in my `message`? (I don't see how in yml.) Am I to add another case in the yml file for this specific model and field (Quoter, weight)? I'm not sure how. Any further detail you could provide would be welcome.

Comment: The easiest way might be to add `:message => "Must be between 10 and 900"` to your validation. I'm not sure how `count` is supposed to be interpolated by default.